# How to distinguish between Dark images and Bright images using Python?

Tags: python, opencv

How to distinguish between Dark images and Bright images using Python?? I am trying to filter images based on the brightness in them.

Comment: calculate average pixel value of an image and define threshold for bright and dark images

Comment: will it not give mean color of the image??

Comment: Convert it into grayscale/binary first

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to go would be to change the color space used to represent your images and then order it by averaging values of the appropriate channel (as suggested in the comments). For example the "L channel" of the HSL representation highlights quite well the brightness on an image.  The conversion from RGB(red green blue) to HSL(hue saturation lightness) is quite easy with opencv :

```
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

imagedark = cv2.imread('testdark.jpg')
hsldark  = cv2.cvtColor(imagedark, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
Lchanneld = hsldark[:,:,1]
lvalueld =cv2.mean(Lchanneld)[0]
cv2.putText(imagedark, str(lvalueld), (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)


image = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
hsl = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
Lchannel = hsl[:,:,1]
lvalue =cv2.mean(Lchannel)[0]
cv2.putText(image, str(lvalue), (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

imagelight = cv2.imread('testbright.jpg')
hsllight  = cv2.cvtColor(imagelight, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HLS)
Lchannell = hsllight[:,:,1]
lvaluel =cv2.mean(Lchannell)[0]
cv2.putText(imagelight, str(lvaluel), (10,450), font, 3, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

cv2.imshow('bright',imagelight)
cv2.imshow('orgid',image)
cv2.imshow('dark',imagedark)
```

output :

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try changing preprocessing function for the image.
you can try following:

```
def preprocess_input(x):
  x /= 127.
  return x
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with np.mean(cv2.imread(image_path))<50 to distinguish black(dark) colored images.